# Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string

Tags: fatal-error

```
$comment = get_comment( $comment_id );
$post    = get_post( $comment->comment_post_ID );
$author  = get_userdata( $post->post_author );
$test = "***" . $comment_id . "***" . $post->ID . "***" . $author . "***";
```

How can I obtain the string `$test` without getting into the error `Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string`?

Comment: `author->user_email` should be `$author->user_email`. Is that error in your code or just in this question?

Comment: I found the solution while writing the question. I've incorrectly written `$author` in place of `$author->user_email`. Anyway I edited my question to make my mistake clear.